# Заменить вторую букву в строке

Tags: python

Подскажите как в строке `str = "qwerty"` заменить вторую буку на z. Тоесть не w на z а именно вторую букву.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
s = 'qwerty'
s1 = s[0] + 'z' + s[2:] # или s[:1] + 'z' + s[2:]
print(s1)
```

Результат:

```
qzerty
```

Comment: а если 3й символ менять то s[1] + 'z' + s[3:]?

Comment: @test `s[:2] + 'z' + s[3:]`. О срезах можно почитать [тут](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html)